# Linq query for creating PIVOT table

Tags: linq, pivot

I have three tables table1, table2 and table3

```
Table1                                                
Id  Data
1   Data1
2   Data2
3   Data3

Table2
Id  Meta data
1   Meta data1
2   Meta data2
“     "
“     "
“     "

Table 3
Id   Data ID  Meta Data ID      Value
1    Data1    Metadata1         Value1
2    Data1    Metadata2         Value2
3    Data2    Metadata1         Value3
4    Data2    Metadata2         Value4
```

I want to create a pivot table by joining these tables using LINQ queries

My result table should look like this

```
Data   Metadata 1  Metadata2  ‘”””   and so on……
Data1  Value1      Value2     
Data2  Value3      Value4
```

What would be the appropriate linq query which may be solution for me to achieve the result?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just do this?  No fancy linq is necessary

```
var dict = new Dictionary<object, PivotedValue>();

foreach(var t in table3){
    if(!dict.ContainsKey(t.DataID)) dict.Add(t.DataID, new PivotedValue{DataID = t.DataID});
    dict[t.DataID].PivotedFields.Add(t.MetaDataID, t.Value);
}


class PivotedValue{

    object DataID {get;set;}
    Dictionary<object, object> PivotedFields {get;set;}

}
```