# Pivot data in linq

Tags: c#, linq, pivot, pivot-without-aggregate

I've a data set which returns me this set of results:

```
Date      |Location |Amount
11.03.2011|Location1|  1000  
11.03.2011|Location2|  1000  
11.03.2011|Location3|  1000  
12.03.2011|Location1|  1000    
12.03.2011|Location2|  1000    
12.03.2011|Location3|  1000  
13.03.2011|Location4|  1000
```

I need to arrange my data in this way:

```
Location | 11.03.2011|12.03.2011|13.03.2011|    
Location1|       1000|      1000|         0|  
Location2|       1000|      1000|         0|  
Location3|       1000|      1000|         0|  
Location4|          0|         0|      1000|
```

Notice that: I don't know the dates in the rows so it's impossible for me to work with "if" clause (e.g.: if `date == DateTime.Parse(11.03.2011)`).

I hope that my explanation is clear.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/963491/pivot-data-using-linq

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=pivot%20linq

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565897/linq-query-for-creating-pivot-table

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pivot an observable collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7106548/pivot-an-observable-collection)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var Locations = Data.GroupBy(l => l.Location);
                .SelectMany( g => 
                             new 
                             { 
                                 LocationName = g.Key, 
                                 Amounts = g 
                             });

Func<Location, bool> matchMonth11 = l => l.Date == "11.03.2011";
Func<Location, bool> matchMonth12 = l => l.Date == "12.03.2011";
Func<Location, bool> matchMonth13 = l => l.Date == "13.03.2011";

var PivotedLocations = new List<PivotedLocation>();

foreach(var item in Locations )
{
    PivotedLocations.Add( new PivotedLocation
                          {
                              LocationName  = item.LocationName,
                              month11Amount = item.Amounts.Where(matchMonth11)
                                              .FirstOrDefault().Amount,
                              month12Amount = item.Amounts.Where(matchMonth12)
                                              .FirstOrDefault().Amount,
                              month13Amount = item.Amounts.Where(matchMonth13)
                                              .FirstOrDefault().Amount
                          });

}
```

You should first define the following class:

```
public class PivotedLocation
{
    public string LocationName { get; set; }
    public int month11Amount { get; set; }
    public int month12Amount { get; set; }
    public int month13Amount { get; set; }
}
```

Then the `PivotedLocations` list should contain the data in a pivoted form like what you want.